# Hide List arrow iOS14 - Xcode 12

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, ios14, xcode12

I have a list in iOS 14 / Xcode 12

Im using the following/tried the following to hide the little arrows in the corner:

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
.background(Color.white)
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to remove the arrow i think is to get the `NavigationLink` out of the `List` and use the `tag` or `isActive` initialiser of `NavigationLink` to define whether or not the link should be activated

Answer (score -1):

**Hey! You need to hide the navigation link. Try This Code Below...**

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: yourItem)) {  //Your Nav Link
    EmptyView()
}.frame(width:0).opacity(0) //Hide Your Link Programmatically
```